# Right Way Of Storing Thread ID In A Static Library

Tags: c++, multithreading, static-libraries

I am developing a multi threaded project and need the main thread's id for various reasons.
Is this the right execution of doing this:

```
//this is in the static library
std::thread::id * FMainThreadID;

//this is in the static library
std::thread::id MainThreadID()
{
    return *FMainThreadID;
}

//this also is in the static library
void InitializeStaticLibrary()
{
    FMainThreadID = &std::this_thread::get_id();
}

int main()
{
    //beginning of the program
    InitializeStaticLibrary();


    //...

    if (MainThreadID() == std::this_thread::get_id())
        std::cout << "This is the main thread\n";
    else
        std::cout << "This is NOT the main thread\n";
}
```

thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what problem you have with the code? What is the problem you have with it? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: i am not having a problem, it just i am not used to idea of objects instantiated on the stack, so i allways use pointers. so i was wondering should use pointer for storing the class or store it directly without using pointers.. sory for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost correct. You must store the actual thread id, not a pointer to it. Like this:

```
//this is in the static library
std::thread::id FMainThreadID;

//this is in the static library
std::thread::id GetMainThreadID()
{
    return FMainThreadID;
}

//this also is in the static library
void InitializeStaticLibrary()
{
    FMainThreadID = std::this_thread::get_id();
}

int main()
{
    //beginning of the program
    InitializeStaticLibrary();


    //...

    if (GetMainThreadID() == std::this_thread::get_id())
        std::cout << "This is the main thread\n";
    else
        std::cout << "This is NOT the main thread\n";
}
```

I think your original code saves a pointer to a temporary and then falls over. It is generally not a good idea to take the address of a return value as these are usually temporaries on the stack.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but the thing you just said made me confused. If using a pointer is a bad idea because of these are usually temporary on the stack that means every time i call the method get_id(), a new object is being created and its pointer adress is changing.. so how this comparing work "GetMainThreadID() == std::this_thread::get_id()"

Comment: The thread id is an opaque type which you can only compare by value. Comparing the pointers to thread ids is wrong (like comparing pointers to ints is wrong if you want to find out whether its the same int or not). Do not worry about new objects being created or copied. A thread id is not a thread and is very 4easy to copy around. You can think of it like a handle, probably 4 or 8 bytes long so it is fine to pass it by value. To be clear: In my variant there is no pointer taking, and no pointer comparison taking place.

Comment: ok thanks Overmann. i did as you said and removed the pointer.